# Bash script commands didnt execute after user switching command

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate some my day to day stuff by bash script. For doing it i need to create the following logic script

1. From root user switch to another linux user
2. Open specified path

Here is my code **logic.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash 
su another_user
cd /home/another_user #tried with sudo too
```

After logic.sh executing

```
. logic.sh
```

I see that **root** user switched to **another_user** but i am staying inside /root directory

What i am doing wrong or bash scripts didnt appropriate for automation logic where user switching logic have

Comment: If you want to su on it's own will keep you in the same directory as before executing su. If  you want to move to that users home directory, use su - another_user

Comment: Наглый Спамер: Did you try using `sudo` as I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When doing `su` you'll start a new shell. When you exit from that shell, the script `login.sh` will continue with `cd /home/another_user`. You could possibly use `sudo -u another_user command_to_execute` to execute a command as the other user.

This is an example of how to run `bash` to be able to supply multiple commands:

```
sudo -u another_user /bin/bash<<EOF
cd
pwd
ls
EOF
```